# limit to output from Application.Inputbox

Tags: excel, user-input, vba

I have a user input box as part of a excel vba macro. I need the user able to type an 11 digit number into this, which is then input into a cell. However, anything greater than a 10 digit number just returns the value of 0. How do I get round this?

My code is:

```
Dim lNum As Long

On Error Resume Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        lNum = Application.InputBox _
         (Prompt:="Enter starting Number", _
                Title:="Starting Number", Type:=1)



Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Range("B1").Value = lNum
```

Comment: Use a `Double` not a `Long`. And don't just shove `On Error Resume Next` into a routine without knowing exactly why! ;)

Comment: A `long` stores values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. That's only 10 digits, hence your 11-digit number will be truncated.

Comment: and +eleventy hundred to @Rory 's comment about `OERN`!!!

Comment: thanks guys. I actually copied that code from elsewhere so I didn't know what the On Error Resume Next meant. Would anyone like to enlighten me??

Comment: It means the code just ignores any errors (such as trying to put too large a number into a variable) and carries on without warning you something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For an **11 digit number** use *Double*:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim lNum As Double
    lNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter starting Number", Title:="Starting Number", Type:=1)
    Range("B1").Value = lNum
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Results in:

[image]